# Incorrect results when using two outer joins

Tags: sql, oracle, join, outer-join

Somehow the record is 10x more using a double left outer join than the original p table. What is the correct syntax for (A left join b) left join C?

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM p
LEFT OUTER JOIN rate ON p.nip = rate.nip
LEFT OUTER JOIN n ON p.pin = n.pin
```

### UPDATE

is it possible to join using to column?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM p
LEFT OUTER JOIN rate ON p.nip = rate.nip
LEFT OUTER JOIN n ON p.pin = n.pin and p.col2 = n.col2;
```

Comment: Is there a relationship between `rate` and `n`?

Comment: Ok, found the issue, the pin is not unique from the n table...

Comment: You can try and check :) Yes, you can join using two, three, four or any other positive number of columns. You can join not by equijoins, but use between and any other relation. You can do all the same that you can with inner joins.

Answer (score 3):

That syntax looks correct.

The problem is likely that you have more than one `rate` record per `p` record for a given `npi`, or that you have more than one `n` record per `p` record for a given `pin`, or a combination of both. In that situation, the database is *supposed* to show you all the combinations, even if it means duplicating records in the `p` table.

You fix it by adding additional conditional expressions to the joins, such that only record record in the additional tables meets the criteria.